# How to restore some Google analytics data?

Tags: google-analytics

Based on erroneous setup some Google Analytics data were wrongly attributed: Organic channel and all of according metrics were added to the Direct channel. *Some* means all data for certain time range.

What is the way to restore these data as clear as possible into the organic channel?

Sorry to all: **forgot to mention**: i'm on ga360.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way. In the free GA version you cannot change data that is already collected at all.

In GA 360 you can change data by overwriting it with a datasource in [query time mode](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6071511?hl=en&ref_topic=6064627). However you cannot change the attribution for direct hits (you would need a utm_id in you destination urls to overwrite campaign and medium, see [campaign data import](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/4522476?hl=en#:%7E:text=Click%20Admin%2C%20and%20navigate%20to,Campaign%20Data%20as%20the%20Type.)).

Comment: Your post pull me in very right and awaiting direction. Could you please become more specific AND, if possible, point me to some further docs, specially about `cannot change the attribution for direct hits`.

Comment: @Evgeniy you can change source and medium via a campaign data import, so in theory it should be possible to change campaign attribution with a query time data import that overwrites the existing source/medium combo. However you need a key to join imported data with existing data, and the campaign data import seems to accept only the campaign code (i.e. utm_id) as join key. Direct hits will not have a utm_id.

Answer (score 1):

You can't modify historical data in Google Analytics, just set a note to remember the issue in those timeframe.

Comment: sorry, forgot to mention: i'm on ga360.